# How to convert to insert mode when editing formulas on Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Google Spreadsheet forces you to be in overtype mode whenever you edit an existing formula.

The only way out I know is to type gibberish. That is, for how every many characters you want to insert, you type however many gibberish -- while still losing a few meaningful formula characters.

Is there a way convert to insert mode when editing formulas on Google Spreadsheets?

Note: `Insert` key does not work

Comment: Are you sure the `Insert` key on your keyboard hasn't been pressed?

Answer (score 3):

The insert toggle is sneaky - it's hard to tell when it is on, and when your context is inside of the formula bar (ie you are editing a formula) it doesn't seem possible to turn it off - context has to be out of that formula bar.

1) Click into some other cell of the sheet

2) Press the `Insert` key.

3) Attempt to edit the formula again.

Comment: It's been a while. I can't find the place where the problematic scenario in my question occurred and can't verify your answer, even though it seems right :/